# Change color of DataGridHyperlinkColumn when row is unfocused

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to change the color of a DataGridHyperlinkColumn when the DataGridRow is selected, but then loses focus. It doesn't seem to respect the following:

```
               <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsFocused}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the DataGridRow is always unfocused, it is the cell that is focused:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=IsFocused}" Value="False">
```

Binding to the parent DataGridCell like this will only work if you have single column though. If you have several columns a cell next to the cell than contains the HyperLink may be focused and then you cannot simply use a RelativeSource binding to bind to the parent cell and check its IsFocused property.

You will then have to do something a bit more complicated like for example handle the GotFocus/LostFocus routed events of the DataGrid and set its Tag property to true/false:

```
    private void dg_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dg.Tag = true;
    }

    private void dg_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dg.Tag = false;
    }
```

You can then bind the DataTrigger to the Tag property of the DataGrid instead of binding to the IsFocused property of the parent DataGridCell:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" GotFocus="dg_GotFocus" LostFocus="dg_LostFocus">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}" />
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Link}">
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <local:Converter x:Key="converter" />
                            <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Chocolate"></Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=Tag}" 
                                                 Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

> Thanks mm8, working as expected. This did create one unexpected issue though. The cell padding is not being respected now. Where would I apply something like <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5" />

In the ElementStyle of the column:

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Link}">
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.CellStyle>
                ...
  </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8, working as expected. This did create one unexpected issue though. The cell padding is not being respected now. Where would I apply something like `<Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5" />`

Comment: In the ElementStyle of the column. I edited my answer. Please remember to vote it up if it helps you :)